# How to declare a variable which store pipe command output in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

```
dt=`echo date --date "-15 min"|awk '{print $4}'`;
dts=`echo sar -P ALL -s $dt`;
echo $dts
```

What is wrong with code?? Here, I want to take 15 min previous sar output but what I get is "sar -P ALL -s min" as output.

Comment: Remove the echo's from inside your backtick'd code... Did you attempt to run these commands outside of the backticks to see what it outputted?

Comment: That first one, for instance: `> echo date --date "-15 min"|awk '{print $4}'` returned `min`. Removing the superfluous `echo` returns the time you are looking for.

Comment: By removing echo it works fine...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use a subshell rather than backticks:

```
#!/bin/bash
DT=$(date --date "-15 min" | awk '{print $4}')
DTS=$(sar -P ALL -s $DT)
echo "$DTS"
```

See: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Comment: Yesss...It works. If you want to take a look ahead you can try the new challenge. I want to show average cpu utilization in last 15 min.

Comment: Linux 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 (vmh-lcag-eai04-test.lsy.fra.dlh.de)    10/12/2016      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

Comment: I am not getting required output

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
dt=`date --date "-15 min"|awk '{print $4}'`;
dts=`sar -P ALL -s $dt`;
echo $dts
```

Eg:

```
user@host:/tmp/test$ ./test.sh
sar -P ALL -s 16:37:44
```

Comment: I want to use it by run time and in a script.